# SimGrid. Abbreviation expansion

Tags: simgrid

I can't find in SimGrid documentation an expansions of abbreviations:
`TMGR`, `TMGRTrace`, `XBT`, `SURF` (Speeded up Robust Features?), `SIRFJni`, `ModelPtr`, `CPUPtr`, `XbtDict`.

How do they expand? Or where can I find info about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of these names are mostly historical, with no real meaning. Here is my understanding of these names. Other may disagree. I don't think that these things are documented, actually.

- TMGR is trace manager
- XBT is the reverse for TBX since it's the toolbox we use
- SURF had only a french meaning, which is something like "server to use fake resources" (Serveur pour l'Utilisation de Ressources Factices), because at the beginning (back in 2003) we thought that it should be an external server. Now it's a part of the library as you know.
- SurfJNI comes from Surf and JNI which is Java Native Interface, the technology allowing to call C++ code from Java.
- (Something)Ptr is just a Pointer over the Something.